# django rest_framework caches sql queries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and React. I am taking over a Django / React project and have an issue where an api url is called:

```
GET /api/admin/parents/
```

but the underlying sql statement:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import *
from rest_framework import permissions, status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, ListCreateAPIView, CreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateAPIView, DestroyAPIView
from .serializers import *
from twilio.rest import Client

class AdminAllParentsView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=False, is_parent=True, is_active=True)
```

does not get re-executed each time the GET /api/admin/parents/ call is performed.

Say for instance.. a sql record is changed so that there are fewer records matching the is_parent=True part of the api call / query... the results returned by the api call don't reflect the real / current status of the query. The GET /api/admin/parents/ still returns the data from a previous, sql query ( a cached version I assume ) and does not re-execute the query.

The urls.py part of this is:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/parents/', AdminAllParentsView.as_view())
```

So how to I get current sql data from this each time I do a api call?

- jack

...  I see in the browser that the /api/admin/parents/ request goes out and returns the old data via json data. It's not a cached browser html thing.

and

... here is the user serializer code... someone said that this might be important too.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from .models import *


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_parent',
            'phone',
            'mobile_phone',
            'address',
            'city',
            'zip',
            'county',
            'agency_name',
            'caseworker_name',
            'caseworker_email',
            'caseworker_phone',
            'caseworker_ext',
            'is_active',
            'agency_approved',
        )


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Heya - have you ruled out browser cacheing of the GET request? eg, can you definitely see the Django server respond to that second call?

Comment: Can you post the UserSerializer, just to confirm nothing strange is happening there?

Comment: I can see the /api/admin/parents GET request hit the chrome network console and the data returned is the incorrect sql results via a valid json string. It was valid before deactivating the record. If I go into mysql and run the query that is being executed it does not show the same data that the /api/admin/parents request returns.

Comment: I updated the original question with the UserSerializer code.